Validez de la expresión "se escriben"
En las matemáticas suelen hallarse varias frases del estilo "sean x e y nuestras variables desconocidas primera y segunda" o "se definen a y b como los términos primero y último de nuestra expresión", etc. Hoy me he topado con la siguiente oración: "se escriben x al primer ordinal e y al ordinal que le sucede". Aunque racionalmente no encuentro por qué este uso de "se escriben" habría de ser inválido en comparación con los usos suseros de "se definen", "sean", etc., no puedo negar que la frase en sí me suena extraña... ¿Es este uso de "se escriben [...] y [...]" alguna vez válido"? Intuitivamente sustituiría el "escriben" por un "escribe", y escribiría en cambio "se escribe x al primer ordinal e y al ordinal que le sucede". ¿Quizá el problema está en que la expresión "escribir a(l)" suena extraña en relación con lo que se está significando en una tal frase? Cfr. "Se escriben (una) carta a Juan y (una) misiva a Raúl".

Existen sujetos compuestos por dos o más sustantivos en singular que concuerdan con el verbo en singular.
Según podemos leer en este trabajo de Soler Arechalde, esta tendencia a usar el verbo en singular con sujeto compuesto es más fuerte cuando los sustantivos son abstractos o cuando, aun siendo concretos, no son tan concretos, como podría ser el caso de las variables "x" e "y".
Además, existe en la oración en cuestión un tema de proximidad que hace que el singular suene perfectamente bien, aunque el plural también sería correcto. Por otra parte, la presencia de "al primer ordinal" y "al ordinal que le sucede" contribuye a que el singular funcione muy bien, como si el segundo "se escribe" estuviera elidido:

Se escribe x al primer ordinal e/(y se escribe) y al ordinal que le sucede.

En cambio, si aparecen los dos componentes del sujeto juntos, aumenta la propensión a usar el verbo en plural:

Se escriben x e y al primer ordinal y al ordinal que le sucede, respectivamente.

En el trabajo citado, encontramos estos ejemplos de sujetos compuestos por sustantivos concretos (pero con cierto grado de abstracción) y abstractos propiamente dichos:


«fuimos en un día medio nublado y que lloviznaba, ahí entraba un frío y una
llovizna por todos lados» (BA22a, 78).
«la práctica y el estudio real viene cuando uno sale de la universidad (CA3,45).


Cabe agregar que el plural se justifica porque estamos frente a una pasiva con "se" con sujeto inanimado, como podemos leer aquí:

• Si el elemento nominal sobre el que recae la acción verbal expresa cosa, debe emplearse la construcción de pasiva refleja; por tanto, el verbo ha de ir en plural si este elemento es plural:

     Se hacen fotocopias.
     Se produjeron irregularidades.
     Se reanudarán los trabajos de rehabilitación.


For better understanding, because of the differences between Spanish and English, we could translate the quoted sentences as:
“we define a and b as the first and last terms of our expression”
“we select x and y to be our first and second unknown variables”
“we write x to the first ordinal and y to the ordinal following it”
In Spanish, the plural is used because of the concordance with x AND y.

Eso no responde a la pregunta original.

It answers the question ‘¿Es este uso de “se escriben [...] y [...]” alguna vez válido’?’
